# Java how do I access text field

Tags: java, textfield

I'm relatively new to programming. Hoping someone can help. I have a button that creates a series of labels and text boxes within a frame once the user enters a number. I'm having trouble access the text boxes once they are created. Can someone point me in the right direction. Code snips below. Thanks.

method to create a label and text box.

```
public JTextField createPrizePanels(){
        JLabel prizePanel = new JLabel("Enter Prize Here", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        prizePanel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        prizePanel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14));
        prizePanel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1);
        prizePanel.setBorder(border);
        prizePanel.setOpaque(true);
        prizePanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        prizePanel.setBounds(setBoundsX, setBoundsY, 120, 60);

        prizeTextBox = new JTextField(50);
        prizeTextBox.setBounds(setBoundsX + 5, setBoundsY + 20, 110, 30);
        prizeTextBox.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        prizeTextBox.setOpaque(true);
        prizeTextBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        prizeTextBox.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        prizeTextBox.setText("No Prize");
        prizeTextBox.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        lp.add(prizePanel);
        lp.add(prizeTextBox); 

        return prizeTextBox;

    }
```

code that creates multiple text boxes bases on input from user.

```
JButton numberOfBallonsButton = new JButton("Set");
        numberOfBallonsButton.setBounds(360,160,95, 0x1e);
        numberOfBallonsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
                numberOfBallons = Integer.parseInt(numberOfBallonsTextBox.getText());
                System.out.println(numberOfBallons);
                lp.remove(numberOfBallonsButton);

                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfBallons; i++ ){
                    createPrizePanels();
                    setBoundsX = setBoundsX +125;
                    if(setBoundsX > 450){
                        setBoundsX = 120;
                        setBoundsY = setBoundsY + 65;
                    }
                }
                lp.add(startGameButton);
            }
        });
```

Up to this point it works fine. However, the user needs to enter text into each text box and press another button. I'm not sure how to access each text field. Thanks in advance.

Comment: access text field means you want to take value from textbox , then the code is `textbox.getText();`

Comment: Thats correct. But I can't access each of the textboxes that I have created.

Answer (score 0):

You are using local fields.you can create global field and the return value of createPrizePanels() is never used and for your case you don't know number of created textfield so you can use List as global field and when you create textfield add it to the list so you access it later from anywhere

Comment: Islam - Thanks for your reply. The textBox is global and I have tried adding it to an ArrayList when they are created, however the value of the text box changes and I can't access the changes.

Comment: Can you submit your code to GitHub and i'll try running it

Comment: I have not idea how to use GitHub